# Reading and effectively storing decimal numbers from character strings without scanning?

Tags: c, string, character

I don't have a lot of experience & I'm trying to read these positive and negative decimal numbers from a character string as a double and store them effectively so that they can be evaluated one-by-one inside the greater for loop. My evaluation works if the numbers are given correctly(commented out), but I'm struggling to read and pass the decimal number through. This code doesn't work & gets stuck in a loop until it seg faults.

Since there are spaces between the inputs, is it best to use strtok() in some way or is the method I'm attempting suitable?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char input[1024] = "3.2 -5.1 3.7";
char numchar[1024];
int i = 0, j = 0;
char *ptr1;
double val;
int main()
{   
    ptr1 = input;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)
    {    

        if(isalnum(input[i]) || input[i] == '.')
            {
            while(input[i] != 32)
                {
                numchar[j++] = input[i];                    
                val = strtod(numchar,&ptr1);
                printf("Val = %lf\n", val);
                printf("ptr = %s", ptr1);
                }
            //tempVal = val
            //push(tempVal);
            }
        //EVALUATION OF CURRENT NUMBER HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `sscanf()`?

Comment: _Side note:_ Doing `for(i=0;i<strlen(input);i++)` increases the effort from O(n) to O(n**2). Better to do: `int len = strlen(input); for(i=0;i<len;i++)` Or, better yet, do: `for(ptr1 = input;  *ptr1 != 0; ++ptr1)` and replace all `input[i]` with `*ptr1` Also, when you do `strtod`, `numchar` does _not_ have a 0 terminator.

Answer (score 1):

`strtod` can iterate through the string parsing `doubles`.
Two pointers are needed.
The second argument to `strtod` will point to the next character that could not be parsed. Use this as the first character to parse on the next iteration.
If `next == each`, then no characters could be parsed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input[1024] = "3.2 -5.1 3.7";
    char *each = input;
    char *next = input;
    double val;

    while ( *next)
    {
        val = strtod ( each, &next);
        if ( next == each) {
            break;
        }
        printf ( "Val = %lf\n", val);
        each = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If your input is indeed separated by one or more spaces, then `strtok()` seems appropriate. `strtok()` is great for general tokenising input strings.

However, because your tokens are numbers, the [`strtod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54766/strtod-3c.html) is much more convenient.

Because you seems to be new to C, here are some suggestions:

- Instead of `32` you should have written `' '` because your looking for a space. The fact that a space has ASCII value 32 is further away from what you're doing. Make your code as meaningful as possible; meaning matters!
- Put more spaces in your code: `#include <stdio.h>`, `for (i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)`, `while (...)`, `strtod(numchar, &ptr1);`.
- You could have written: `char input[] = "3.2 -5.1 3.7";` here, without defining the size.
- Great you placed your `{`s on the next further empty line. This makes code blocks visually consistent and avoids the need to sometimes (i.e. lack of consistency) add an empty line at top of the block when for example the `if`-condition spans multiple lines.

Comment: `strtok()` is overkill here if the numbers are separated by whitespace as `strtod()` will skip over leading whitespace, and the return a pointer to the first character after the number parsed. So it can be used directly to parse the string.  And it has the added benefit that it doesn't modify the input string so it won't blow up on a string literal like `strtok()`.